# problem with including fmt library in several cpp files

Tags: c++, fmt

Good day! 
I installed the fmt library in Ubuntu. Added it in my project

```
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/format-inl.h"
```

to use `fmt::format_int` и `fmt::format`. I added library headers in several cpp files of my project. During linkage I got the mistake "multiple definition":

> obj/container.o: In function `fmt::v7::format_error::~format_error()': container.cpp:(.text+0x40e): multiple definition of` fmt::v7::format_error::~format_error()'
> obj/line.o:line.cpp:(.text+0x40e): first defined here

I've read something about this mistake. It is recommended to divide declaration and implementation in h and cpp files, to set some status to objects that causes mistake and so on. But all this recommendations imply editing of library (not my!) code! 
What is wrong?

I do the following
compilation of files - one by one
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/line.o -c /home/...//line.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/container.o -c /home/...//container.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/geometryObject.o -c /...//geometryObject.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/model.o -c /home/...//model.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/point.o -c /home/...//point.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/main.o -c /home/...//main.cpp
Linking - error here 
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o myapp obj/line.o obj/container.o obj/geometryObject.o obj/model.o obj/point.o obj/main.o

Comment: How are you, or how is your build system, linking the code?

Comment: Dont include "fmt/core.h" and "fmt/format-inl.h", just include fmt/format.h, it will include the other two.

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o myapp obj/line.o obj/container.o obj/geometryObject.o obj/model.o obj/point.o obj/main.o

Comment: I deleted format-inl.h and core.h. But plenty of mistakes "multiple definition" and among them "undefined reference to". It seems the same thing. Didn't make any sense. In official recommendation it is said to include all h files (https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html). But i think you are 100% right. At least about core.h.

Comment: What version of the fmt library are you using? The one in your Ubuntu installation, or one that you self-installed?

Comment: Master version from github.

Comment: How are you installing it? In particular, what are you doing with `src/format.cc`, which is *not* a header file?

Comment: Installation is here (https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html). cmake + make + sudo make install. I don't have anything to do with *.cc files according to installation procedure.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to include more information, then. Include the *exact* steps you used, not only to build the fmt library itself, but also how you tried to compile and link your own code. Without that, we're just stabbing in the dark. You may end up doing some ["rubber duck debugging"](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) in the process.

Comment: @jjramsey have you tried to use fmt library in several files yourself?

Comment: No. From Googling around, though, it looks like the problem is that you're `#include`ing `fmt/format-inl.h`. Try removing that, and then compile with the flag `-DFMT_HEADER_ONLY`.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be including `fmt/format-inl.h` because it's an internal header. Please see the [documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html) for the list of public headers and what they provide.

Comment: Hey men, I'm sorry for my stupid question and my not attentive reaction on right answers! I followed your advice and "multiple definition" disappeared. Thank you. But I got another mistake - "undefined reference to". I found solution [here](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2157). I'm not professional programmer; could you give me a hint: why #define FMT_HEADER_ONLY should be placed above #include "fmt/format.h"? For what FMT_HEADER_ONLY is needed for? And so on. I just what to understand a general rule of these things - how do they work.

Comment: @AlexanderVachenko "undefined reference to *what*?" That's the important part. Also, very likely, you shouldn *not* use `FMT_HEADER_ONLY`, lest reading the official documentation says you should.

Comment: @AlexanderVachenko If you look at the bottom of the `fmt/format.h` header, you'll see that if `FMT_HEADER_ONLY` is defined, then `FMT_FUNC` is defined as inline, and `fmt/format-inl.h` is then included. It looks like defining `FMT_FUNC` as inline leads to the functions in `fmt/format-inl.h` being inlined--which avoids the "multiple definition" problem.

Comment: Make sure to link the the fmt library (libfmt.a on Linux).